# Spotify Auth Issues in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, spotify

When I press the button in my chrome extension, a spotify auth webpage appears, then I enter my login info and click login then the window disappears and all I see is this in the console (to 'inspect' chrome extension 'popup'):

```
logging in attempt                                                       login.js:27
attempted                                                                login.js:31       
undefined                                                                login.js:29       
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Authorization page could not be loaded.     login.html:1
```

When I load unpacked extension, update, open the console for the chrome extension, then run through the process again, the spotify auth webpage does not appear.  I have to wait a couple hours and then try again.  Does anyone know why this is so?

The next issue would be why is the redirectUri undefined and not set to the URI which contains the access token or code that I need to run the spotify player (web playback api)?

manifest.json

```
    {
      "name": "xxx",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "xxx",
      "permissions": ["identity", "declarativeContent", "storage", "*://*.spotify.com/*", "*://*.chromiumapp.org/*"],
      "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://sdk.scdn.co; object-src 'self'",
      "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "login.html",
        "default_icon": {
          "16": "images/get_started16.png",
          "32": "images/get_started32.png",
          "48": "images/get_started48.png",
          "128": "images/get_started128.png"
        },
        "icons": {
          "16": "images/get_started16.png",
          "32": "images/get_started32.png",
          "48": "images/get_started48.png",
          "128": "images/get_started128.png"
        }
      }
    }
```

login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
      <script src="background.js"></script>
      <script src="login.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <form id="form" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="label1"></div><br>
    <input type='text' id='field1'><br>
    <div id="label2"></div><br>
    <input type='password' id='field2'><br>
    <input type='button' id='submit'>
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

login.js

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Username"
      document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = "Password"
      document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = "Submit"
      
      document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
        var login = [document.getElementById("form").elements[0].value, document.getElementById("form").elements[1].value];
        document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = login[0]
        document.getElementById("label2").innerHTML = login[1]
       
        var my_extension_id = "xxx";
        
        var my_client_id = "xxx";
        
        var scopes = "user-read-email user-read-private user-read-playback-state playlist-modify-public user-modify-playback-state playlist-modify-private user-follow-modify user-read-currently-playing user-follow-read user-library-modify user-read-playback-position playlist-read-private user-library-read streaming";
        
        var redirectUri = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("xxx");
        //var redirectUri = "https://" + my_extension_id + ".chromiumapp.org";
        
        var auth_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?" + 
        "client_id=" + my_client_id + 
        "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirectUri) + 
        "&response_type=code" + 
        "scope=" + encodeURIComponent(scopes) + 
        "show_dailog=true";
    
        console.log("logging in attempt");
        chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({'url':auth_url,'interactive':true}, function(redirect_url) {
            console.log(redirect_url)
        });
        console.log("attempted");
    
      }
        
    });
```

Comment: background.js
```
'use strict';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({color: '#3aa757'}, function() {
    console.log("The color is green.");
  });
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'developer.chrome.com'},
        })
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I saw the "show_dailog" typo and changed it to "show_dialog" with no change in app response.